# why zip failure while resuing a map?(python function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I construct a map `columns = map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description)`,and use it in a for loop:

```
for r in rows:
    proxy_list.append(Proxy(dict(zip(columns, [e for e in r]))))
```

But I find the result is weird.Only first zip successed, all of left ones `return {}` .

sample for test:

```
r = ('204.93.54.15', '7808', 6, 0, '', '2013-11-12 20:27:54', 0, 3217.0, 'United States', 'HTTPS')
description = (('ip', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('port', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('level', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('active', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('time_added', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('time_checked', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('time_used', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('speed', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('area', None, None, None, None, None, None), ('protocol', None, None, None, None, None, None))
columns = map(lambda x: x[0], description)
```

My test result is as below:

```
>>> dict(zip(columns, [e for e in r]))
{'protocol': 'HTTPS', 'level': 6, 'time_used': 0, 'ip': '204.93.54.15', 'area': 'United States', 'port': '7808', 'active': 0, 'time_added': '', 'speed': 3217.0, 'time_checked': '2013-11-12 20:27:54'}
>>> zip(columns, [e for e in r])
<zip object at 0x0000000004079848>
>>> dict(zip(columns, [e for e in r]))
{}
```

Comment: Test `list(zip(columns, [e for e in r]))`.

Comment: @hcwhsa it `return []', `Proxy` is a class which accept only one dict type argument.

Comment: I think some functions will return an iterable that can be iterated over only once.  I've had this happen to me with `shlex` and `open` I believe.

Comment: What is the type of `columns` and `r`?

Comment: To add on, can you do `r = list(r)` before executing the code two times, and share if you have the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator in Python3, so after the first iteration it is exhausted:

```
>>> columns = map(int, '12345')
>>> list(zip(columns, range(5)))
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
>>> list(zip(columns, range(5)))
[]
```

Convert it to a `list` first:

```
>>> columns = list(map(int, '12345'))
>>> list(zip(columns, range(5)))
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
>>> list(zip(columns, range(5)))
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
```

For your case it would be better to use a `list comprehension`:

```
columns = [x[0] for x in  description]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [Python3 map(..)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). It does not return a list; but returns an iterator. So if you plan on reusing, then do:

```
columns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description))
```